# How to budget or gain control of daily spending if suffering from OCD (Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder)?

Tags: budget, expenses, spending, psychology

I want to get better at saving money as I am a spendthrift. I am not always able to control myself since I suffer from Obsessive Compulsive Disorder (OCD). I am not able to spend money wisely since the symptoms of this disorder are so aggravating, though I take pills for it daily.

I make rash decisions about spending money because of OCD. How can I help kill this anxiousness that is affecting my ability to budget?

Comment: Perhaps you could use your "OCD" nature to your benefit.  Try downloading an app like mint to your smartphone, or checking it each day.  They have a lot of metrics you can look at, perhaps you can wire your brain to push yourself to increasing net worth or lowering debt through the use of their goals.

Comment: Whenever possible, disconnect your OCD from your behavior.  Think about what your personality enables you to choose to do rather than what you feel it makes you do.

Comment: Scott I think you might be making a common mistake of confusing OC Personality disorder.  (The stereotypical neat freak) with Obsessive Compulsive Disorder. (see http://ocd.about.com/od/otheranxietydisorders/a/OCD_OCPD.htm) Something like mint still might be useful, but there really isn't something like an "OCD" nature.

Comment: @Himanshu It seems that you are in India given your other questions.  It seems that: www.perfios.com  might be a good bet for you, but there appears to be a few competitors as well which might serve you better.  Good luck gaining control of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OCD is a serious condition and honestly you should avoid taking advice on how to deal with it from strangers on the internet.  I am guessing you are having problems getting a good answer because few people are willing to risk harming someone in a vulnerable state.  You need someone who can work with you throughout the process not some one time quick fix solution dreamed up by some anonymous people on the internet.

I wish you luck and please do not take this as blowing you off.  My best suggestion is find someone you trust and engage them in helping you gain control over your behavior.

Comment: This is exactly why my comment was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Scott - I was not trying to address your comment which is a valid approach IMO.  But I did not want the OP to think we were just ignoring his question either.

Comment: totally agree, had he not received any answer I was going to move the comment to an answer; however you articulated my reasoning for now "answering" far better than I would have.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Chad, seek out a personal counselor before making any huge decisions.

I did want to add that if you still want to talk to people about this question try www.stuckinadoorway.org.  There you will get other OCD suffers take on this and all sorts of questions.

My only advice directly to your question is to make saving as regular and automated as possible.  Contribute to any work based savings scheme or have a bank make a regular transfer into a savings account.

Answer (score 1):

I drove myself into serious debt until a friend persuaded me to start budgeting and told me about Out Of The Dark Budgeting.  This free budgeting site made a huge difference for me because it made money management so simple for me and it provides many good suggestions and advice.  I particularly like the cash put aside feature and credit card debt terminator both of which helped me move from bad spending habits to responsible money management so now I waste less and have more for what I really need and love, and most importantly, I am on my way to being debt free, a very powerful feeling already.  Good luck.